# How to read record from one table and write to another table with the corresponding record?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to read from one access table send an email, "Email1" and then write to the corresponding record "Email2" with the date. To find the corresponding Record, the fields RecID from both tables will match. I keep returning the error that "Syntax Error" highlighting this line below " rs1.Edit where rs!MaxOfForm_Record_Number = rs1.MaxOfForm_Record_Number"

```
   Function EmailTest1()

    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim strBody As String
    Dim strBody2 As String
    Dim strRecipient As String
    Dim rs1 As Recordset
    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Email2")
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Email1")
    Dim strName As String
    Dim strProject As String
    Dim strLastDate As String
    Dim strNow As String
    Dim emailcheck As String

    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst

    For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount

        If IsNull(rs!EmailStat) = True Then
         strNow = Now()
         strName = rs!Inspected_By
         strProject = rs!Site_Location
         strLastDate = rs!LastOfDate_Time_of_Inspection
         strBody2 = "BLah blah text "

         rs1.Edit where rs!RecID = rs1.RecID
         rs1![EmailStat].Value = strNow
         rs1.Update

         strBody = "blahblah"
         strRecipient = rs!Email
         DoCmd.SendObject , , , strRecipient, , , "Subject", strBody, False, False


         End If
         rs.MoveNext
    Next i

    Set rs = Nothing

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the record - then edit it
You can't do that on one line like you're trying

Replace:

```
rs1.Edit where rs!RecID = rs1.RecID
```

With:

```
rs1.FindFirst "RecID = " & rs!RecID
rs1.Edit
```

> **EDIT - add check for NoMatch**

**NOTE** - You should also check for rs1.NoMatch after your FindFirst attempt,
unless you know for sure that there's a RecID match for every record

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I keep getting that "Operation is not supported for this object" but when I step into on Access, I can see it matching up the RecID's.

Comment: rs1.FindFirst "RecID = " & rs!RecID

Comment: You may have to specify dbOpenDynaset for your recordset - I'm assuming that both recordsets are just tables?

Comment: Yup both are just tables

Comment: Change your open recordset to `Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Email2", dbOpenDynaset)`

Comment: That seems to have done it! It seems to only write on the first record in Email1, however, even though I see it searching for the recID's that match.

Comment: You might need to tell it to go back to the start before searching with `rs1.MoveFirst`

Answer (score 2):

I would not bother with the whole OpenRecordset deal for a simple update, I would just do:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Email2 SET EmailStat=#" & strNow & "# WHERE RecID=" & rs!RecID
```

A additional note:
RecordCount is not exactly trustworthy. I prefer to loop like this:

```
rs.MoveFirst
Do while Not rs.EOF
    {Do Stuff}
    rs. MoveNext
  Loop
```

(this does not check for no records at all, to check for no records at all use:
`rs.EOF=True AND rs.BOF=true`
before rs.MoveFirst, otherwise you will get an error)

Comment: Thanks! Changed the loop per your suggestion.

Comment: "not bother with the whole OpenRecordset deal for a simple update" gets my +1